# TreeNode.NextVisibleNode broken?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am wondering how the `TreeNode` property `NextVisibleNode` is defined semantically. I noticed that it does *not* correspond with a `TreeNode`'s `IsVisible` property.

Consider a `Windows.Forms.Form` with a `TreeView` holding more `TreeNode`s than it can display in it's client area (i.e. the scroll bar appears).

When trying to iterate only over those `TreeNode`s that are visible in the client area with the following code...

```
int numVisible = 0;

for (TreeNode node = treeView.TopNode;
     node != null;
     node = node.NextVisibleNode)
{
    // Do something...
    ++numVisible;
}
```

...actually *all* `TreeNode`s below the first visible `TreeNode` are counted. Although `TopNode` works as expected, one has to extend the `for`'s condition to be `node != null && node.IsVisible` in order to iterate over the correct subset of `TreeNode`s.

Is this behaviour of `NextVisibleNode` intended or possibly due to a bug?

Comment: so your wanting to just iterate over the visible nodes ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout That is correct. I figured using `TopNode` and `NextVisibleNode` yields shorter and more readable code than iterating over all `TreeNode`s recursively. However, `NextVisibleNode`'s odd behaviour confused me.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: The name is confusing but it really means the next node that follows the node and isn't collapsed.  In other words, a node that the user could see by scrolling the control.  So sure, also testing IsVisible ensures that you only select nodes that are visible without scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is either "as designed" or a bug.  But sounds like your approach of checking `IsVisible` is the way to go:

[What does TreeNode.NextVisibleNode have to return](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/1002b7e8-6e0e-4493-874a-0245e9167e13)

Perhaps the `NextVisibleNode` refers to expansion state (i.e. child nodes that aren't expanded don't count as visible), but not the actual `IsVisible` property.  That's the behavior I'm seeing with my limited testing. And thats the only thing that seems to differentiate it from `NextNode`

Comment: That is not quite correct. Unlike `NextVisibleNode`, `NextNode` only returns child or sibling `TreeNode`s, but never "cousin" `TreeNode`s from another branch. Nevertheless, I think you and Hans Passant got it right: "visible" probably referrs to expansion state. Either by (poor) design or because of a bug.